# IsNumeric() not working with Request.QueryString

Tags: asp-classic, isnumeric

I'm having problems trying to get IsNumeric to work properly with Request.QueryString.

The server is Windows 2008 R2 / IIS7.5

My code could not be any simpler:

```
    <%@ LANGUAGE=VBScript %>
    <% Response.Write "IsNumeric: " & IsNumeric(Request.QueryString("")) %>
```

My URL:
        http://localhost.com/default2.asp?44hjh

The output:
        IsNumeric: True

If I change my code to this, then I get the desired outcome:

```
    <%@ LANGUAGE=VBScript %>
    <% Response.Write "IsNumeric: " & IsNumeric(Request.QueryString("test")) %>
```

My URL:
        http://localhost.com/default2.asp?test=44hjh

The output:
        IsNumeric: False

Why does IsNumeric not work when I don't specify a specific querystring element? And more importantly, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request.QueryString("")` doesn't exist and thus returns `NULL` -- there isn't a parameter that is a blank.  `IsNumeric` of a `NULL` value will return True.

Instead of using `Request.QueryString("")`, you can either supply the parameter as you did in your 2nd example, or just use `Request.QueryString` by itself assuming no other parameters are being passed to your page:

```
<% Response.Write "IsNumeric: " & IsNumeric(Request.QueryString) %>
```

Comment: Fantastic, your example works perfectly! Very grateful, thank you :)

Comment: @Rich -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `isnumeric` of a null value returns an integer type.  That's why you get a *TRUE* in the first case. Whereas you are checking for a string type using the `isnumeric` in the second case.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for the reply! Any suggestions for how to check if it actually is numeric?